# JQuery - Change the function bound to a $elem.on('click') event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this event handler that looks something like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.close, #mask', Popup.close);
```

and I can't figure out how to change the function (Popup.close) dynamically for this event. The Popup.close variable is a local function that can be set by calling Popup.setClose(func), and I was hoping that this would then change the function that is called when this event is fired. I then realized that I may have to unbind the event, and bind the new function every time I want to change the Popup.close() function. Regardless, I could not figure out how to unbind and event that was previously bound using the .on('click',...) method.

So what I am asking is, what is the best way to change the executing function for a jQuery event bound using the .on() method?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.off("click")` to remove the event and then attach the new event, but this will remove all click events.

```
$(document).off('click');
```

Or to preserve other events that may have been attached:

```
$(document).off('click', 'a.close, #mask');
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Xzjj/

Comment: Hmm ya that should work. Is there any other more efficient method? Is there is no way to change the handler function without unbinding the event?

Comment: You could chain the methods `$(document).off("click", "a.close #mask").on(....`, other than that I'm not aware of a better way.